# Copy and paste java code spacing gives errors

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: code errors]

I copied and pasted code and Eclipse is giving me an error. I can fix it by deleting the spacing at the beginning of the lines but that is very tedious. It is the most recent version. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `f` in `Eclipse`. It auto formats the code.

Comment: I can see you have public void run, but no thread?

Comment: Didn't work. The error messages all say syntax error delete this token.

Comment: The errors that you are getting is not because of copy and paste or extra line. My guess is there is some issue with your code just check it.

Comment: You would not get errors for formatting (unless it is some plugin thing like Checkstyle that I am not aware of), it is some other compilation or workspace issue.

Comment: Sam, can you post your code.

Comment: There should be no problem with formatting of the code, it's java, indentation doesn't matter. This is either a strange bug of eclipse (I doubt it) or you don't have correct project setup, e.g. missing external libraries or incorrect jdk.

Comment: Could it be some extraneous non visible character? Try copying the "token" into an editor and displaying the unicode.

Comment: @SamKirkiles Did you solve the problem? if yes how?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning on display of control characters. Under Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors. There is a checkbox labeled "Show whitespace characters".  Then you could potentially do a global replace if that is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen such errors in the past in other language (ActionScript) in eclipse. The problem there was that the used whitespace character was not the usual one to encode a blank but the one that encoded a blank that should not be broken apart into two lines. I would expect normaly this should not be an issue in Java because it uses unicode ... but probably your file has some other encoding (not unicode)!?

You should check:

1. Does the encoding of your file support unicode (in the eclipse "Properties" of the file). Probably changing the encoding solves your problem.
2. Look in some hex editor into the problematic file and check the character of the problematic blanks. Probably you have copy/paste your code from some webpage and there was such a character used to prevent the browser to break the code into multiple lines.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/) can help identify the character.

Answer (score 0):

There are different unseen characters. What I do is to paste to a text editor (such as Notepad ++) and I say remove formatting. It removes these unseen characters and copy from it and paste it to the eclipse without any problem.